# Offboard user on G Suite/Gmail without bouncing emails

Tags: google-workspace-for-business

We've realized recently that user accounts were not being suspended when people off-boarded. When asked why not the answer was we still wanted to allow incoming emails to be forwarded to others who had taken over the role.

The problem with this method is all they did was change the password which still left the account open to recovery by a former user based on Phone/Email. The one option is to of course remove the recovery email/phone and then change the password.

This still seems quite clunky to me vs out right suspending the user. Is there a way to effectively suspend the user/prevent Login while still allowing emails to flow?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to achieve this:

Option 1:

1. Rename the account
2. Suspend the account
3. Give another user the alias of the former employee so the emails can continue to flow and be managed.

Option 2:

1. Rename the account
2. Suspend the account
3. Create a Google Group and name it the original former employee's email address

This method, emails sent to the former employee will be sent to the Group where you can assign other employees to manage the communications. Personally, option 2 is easier to manage because you can quickly forget who you gave the alias to later on.